# php recursive function using static variables

Tags: php, recursion

I have:

```
function test()
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count;
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }
    $count--;
}
```

How exactly does the `$count--` work within this recursion?

When the count finally reaches 10 the immediately following `$count--` is executed. But what happens from there?

Comment: I guess it will finish the execution of any of the active recursions (e.g. if you've ended up 10 levels deep, you'll get $count being reduced, back to one) - demo (doing this yourself probably would've told you: https://eval.in/92574

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will increment count from 1 to 10 and if you echo the last line `$count--;` it will decrement from 10 to 1, like:
`12345678910` and $count-- would make it `10987654321`
I meant like:

```
function test()
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count;
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }
    echo $count--;
}
test();
```

would produce `1234567891010987654321`

Comment: Yeah I didnt read the question right. You win : ) I noticed the increment and decrement now which is a bit weird. But I can see how the stack will work with this.

Comment: So when the recursive function backtracks in the stack after the condition has been met it just jumps to $count--? Backtracking 9  times from where it entered the recursion thus reducing the count 9 times?